# All Android Projects have a red cross with them in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

Today when I started my Eclipse IDE, all my Android projects have a "Red Cross" next to them!I tried to "Clean" all my projects but with no added benefit! I see no red line in any of my source code (that indicates an error) and am stumped on what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Browse inside project and see what files the reports come from.

Comment: Check the _Error_ and _Output_ views, perhaps you failed to configurate the _Android SDK_ appropriately.

Comment: on hover to red cross what message comes .......there are many reasons for this so provide some more info to figure out the right one for you...

Comment: provide some more info dude. Look into Error window.

Comment: I see this in the "Problem" Tab: Description Resource Path Location Type
Error generating final archive: Debug Certificate expired on 5/7/12 10:35 AM ContentProviderPeopleDemo  Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your time and answers. I have found a solution to this issue online. Below is the link for any one who runs into this in the future (seems likely to be an annual thing as the Android debug key is valid for only 365 days!)

http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/eclipse-throws-debug-certificate-expired/